# Windows utility to keep all previously open files/programs on restart

Tags: windows, open-source, osx

I'm using a Macbook with Windows Bootcamp. I like how on Mac OSX when I reboot my laptop, my previously open programs/files start up again ready for me to continue work. Is there anything like this for Windows?

I don't usually turn my laptop off - I just hibernate it instead. I don't close my programs and I use [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/), so I have loads of programs open. I'm asking because sometimes I need to restart my laptop because something isn't working, or I've just installed something that requires a restart.

Thanks.

Comment: @ṧнʊß point taken and suggestion revoked

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/94943/restoring-open-software-after-a-restart-event-in-windows